# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) appears when running processing P2D, P3D on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: java, dll, processing

I got the error message below when running my processing code on windows 10 64-bit.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006e755080, pid=4380, tid=0x0000000000000fb4
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>   C  [atio6axx.dll+0x125080]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    C:\Users\TRANSARTNCTU4\Documents\processing-3.3.3-windows64\processing-3.3.3\hs_err_pid4380.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>    The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>    Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize). For more information, read revisions.txt and Help → Troubleshooting.

Environment:
Operating System: windows 10 64-bit
Processing version: 3.3.3
Graphic card: Radeon RX570

I have been working for this problem since a month ago, and I have tried to upgrade my driver. However it didn't work. Can anyone save me?

Here is the [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KTmERTqKb8U2JrcWZXT0s3T0E/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Are you trying to run your Processing code, or are you trying to run the Processing editor?

Comment: I am trying to run my Processing code. Then I would get this fatal error when I use the "P2D" or "P3D" mode to render my code.

Comment: What version of Java do you have? Have you tried uninstalling Java and Processing and then reinstalling both? Restarting the computer? Googling the errors in the log?

Comment: @Vivian Might be related to GL calls and how they reach the GPU, hard to tell without peaking at the code. Just to narrow down: are you able to run other Processing examples using GL calls ? (e.g. **Examples > Demos > Graphics > LowLevelGLVboSeparate**) What about a sketch that simply contains:`size(128,128,P3D);` ? Does that crash too ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you very much! I tried to run the example code in the Processing, and found that it can run on my computer. Then I tried to test my code to find which part made Processing crash. Finally, I found a line of code "frameRate(30)" which made Prcessing crach. After I deleted it, Processing can run well. However, I still don't understand why it could cause the crashing, haha.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you very much for your advice, too. :)